# Detect user response to text message and respond with Flask/Twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio, sms, background-process

Hey guys I have a question about trying to appropriately respond to a message a user sends to twilio:

```
@app.route('/week1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def week1():

    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    number = request.form['From']

    part = Part.query.filter_by(phone_num=number).first()
    session['phone_num'] = part.phone_num
    session['responded'] = False

    send_text_message('+1XXXXXXXXX', number, message_library['WELCOME'])

    time.sleep(10)

    send_text_message('+1XXXXXXXXX', number, message_library['T2'])

    time.sleep(10)

    if not part.baseline: # check db status 

        send_text_message('+1XXXXXXXXX', number, message_library['T4_Q'][0]) # ask question 

        body = request.form['Body'].lower() # get body parameter from request

        if 't' in body:
            resp.message(message_library['T4_Q'][1]) # response if true
            responded = True
            time.sleep(10)

        elif 'f' in body:
            resp.message(message_library['T4_Q'][2]) # response if false
            responded = True
            time.sleep(10)

    send_text_message('+1XXXXXXXXX', number, message_library['T6'][0])

    if not part.baseline:
        send_text_message('+1XXXXXXXXX', number, message_library['BASELINE_1'])

    return str(resp)
```

When I test this, the messages send per 10 sec interval but when the question is asked and I respond with "t" or "f", the program continues on to the next message `message_library['T6'][0]`. Does anybody have an idea in how I can achieve the functionality I want (whether it includes some sort of threading/multiprocessing, task scheduler, db method, etc.)